# Parallel computing problems

Tags: r

I seem to have run on a problem when trying to run a parallel computing in R

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
Loading required package: Rmpi
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/PCCasa/Documents/R/win-   library/3.2/Rmpi/libs/x64/Rmpi.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The system is unable to find the package specified.

Error in makeMPIcluster(spec, ...) : 
the `Rmpi' package is needed for MPI clusters.
registerDoParallel(cl)
Error in registerDoParallel(cl) : Object 'cl' not found
```

windowsproduces an error which advises to either repair or reinstall msmpi.dll. Could you kindly let me know what the best prodecure would be as to solve this issue

Comment: Can you please translate those error messages into english?

Comment: The error is because I have to repair or reinstall msmpi.dll. The system outputs this errors

Comment: Here is information on how to install Rmpi: https://bioinfomagician.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/installing-rmpi-mpi-for-r-on-mac-and-windows/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

None, the RMPI spawn function is not implemented for Windows. Here is the excerpt of the RMPI code.

```
if (.Platform$OS=="windows"){
    #stop("Spawning is not implemented. Please use mpiexec with Rprofile.")
    workdrive <- unlist(strsplit(getwd(),":"))[1]
    workdir <- unlist(strsplit(getwd(),"/"))
    if (length(workdir) > 1)
        workdir <-paste(workdir, collapse="\\")
    else
        workdir <- paste(workdir,"\\")
    localhost <- Sys.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")
    networkdrive <-NULL #.Call("RegQuery", as.integer(2),paste("NETWORK\\",workdrive,sep=""), 
                    #PACKAGE="Rmpi")
    remotepath <-networkdrive[which(networkdrive=="RemotePath")+1]
    mapdrive <- as.logical(mapdrive && !is.null(remotepath))
    arg <- c(Rscript, R.home(), workdrive, workdir, localhost, mapdrive, remotepath)
    if (.Platform$r_arch == "i386") 
        realns <- mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves32.cmd", 
            package = "Rmpi"), slavearg = arg, nslaves = nslaves, 
            info = 0, root = root, intercomm = intercomm, quiet = quiet)
    else 
        realns <- mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves64.cmd", 
                    package = "Rmpi"), slavearg = arg, nslaves = nslaves, 
            info = 0, root = root, intercomm = intercomm, quiet = quiet)
}
```